# Prove that $G =\{(l_1 ,l_2) :l_1\ \text{is parallel to}\ l_2\},$

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $L$ be the set of all the straight lines in the plane. Let $G$ and $H$ be the following relations in $L$:
$G =\{(l_1 ,l_2) :l_1\ \text{is parallel to}\  l_2\}$,

**My attempt**:

The symmetric property is true since if $ l_1 $ is parallel to $ l_2 $, then $ l_2 $ is parallel to $ l_1 $. And the same transitive, it is easily followed.

But the reflexive is not fulfilled, since a line is not parallel to itself.

Comment: This depends on the definition of parallel. Some authors allow lines to be parallel to themselves and others don't.

Comment: I suppose, from the context, that the goal is to prove that $G$ is an equivalence relation on $L$. Note that nowhere in the title or body of the question you make that explicit. Anyway there're only two hypothesis: either you allow a straight line to be parallel to itself, as CyclootomicField suggests, or you can conclude that $G$ is not an equivalence relation. Except you fix the definition by claiming that $l_1Gl_2$ iff $l_1=l_2$ or $l_1$ is parallel to $l_2$.